# System Identification using LMS Adaptive Filter

Tags: adaptive-filters

I just have a question about using an least-mean-squares algorithim adaptive filter for system identification. Consider the following
[image]

I am told that as the error converges to a small value, the adaptive filter coefficients w[k] will indeed repersent the unknown system h[k]. Now, that doesn't make sense to me since the n[k] is being used in the error calculation.

**Won't the adaptive filter coefficients w[k] now repersent the unknown system coefficients h[k] AND the noise n[k]?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an LMS estimator will, over time, "average out" uncorrelated zero-mean noise. It's pretty much in the name.

But yes, you're right, there *is* a noise component in the estimate; one of the qualities of an estimator is how little the noise variance influences the estimate variance after a given length of observation.

That's the case, however, for *all* estimators: you measure signal + noise, and you estimate parameters from that. The parameters *must* be somewhat noisy; otherwise, there's something broken with your noise model.

Comment: Ah. I assume, this would work without the noise too then.

Comment: it probably does in this case, but there's estimators which **need** the noise to work.